# What's the difference between KVM, QEMU and libvirt?

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt, virsh

I'm trying to understand how all the components of the VM ecosystem fit together.

What's the difference between:

- KVM
- QEMU
- libvirt

Which is controlled by `virsh` and `virt-install`?

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087232/how-does-libvirt-communicate-with-kvm/41273340#41273340) says that libvirt is an abstraction ontop of QEMU, which is an abstraction ontop of KVM. However [the official QEMU docs](https://qemu.weilnetz.de/doc/qemu-doc.html#Introduction) say that QEMU is a processor emulator, which sounds like the lowest level component.

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/208693/difference-between-kvm-and-qemu

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Qemu is the lowest level that emulates processor and peripherals.  KVM is to accelerate it if the CPU has VT enabled.  Libvirt provides a daemon and client to manipulate VMs for convenience. See also [Difference between KVM and QEMU](https://serverfault.com/q/208693/293440) on Server Fault.