# What are equivalences to QEMU/KVM in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, kvm, qemu

Are QEMU and KVM both kernel modules?

In VirtualBox, what are the equivalences to these kernel modules?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the unaccelrated solutions by qemu and virtualbox not use any kernel module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

KVM is implemented as a number of kernel modules, `kvm` and an architecture-specific module (`kvm-amd` for AMD, `kvm-intel` for Intel). QEMU is a user-space application which can use KVM if it’s available but doesn’t need it.

VirtualBox also has several kernel modules, the main one of which is `vboxdrv`. This handles ring 0 duties for VirtualBox.

The two sets of kernel modules are similar but not identical, *i.e.* their features don’t overlap exactly. The virtualisation details in both setups are quite different.

(If you look through VirtualBox you’ll find references to KVM, but it doesn’t *use* KVM. It contains some source code referencing KVM, because it includes QEMU’s recompiler, but the KVM support is explicitly disabled. It also provides a KVM-compatible paravirtualisation interface for guests. You must take care [never to use different virtual machine hosts with hardware acceleration in parallel](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt), because they are liable to walk over each other and potentially crash the host — so you can run multiple VMs with QEMU and KVM, but don’t try running VMs with QEMU/KVM and VirtualBox simultaneously.)

Comment: Thanks. How do I know if I run a KVM (or Virtualbox) VM with hardware acceraltion or not?

Comment: Is QEMU really a user space process instead of a kernel module? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506417/674 says "Qemu is the lowest level that emulates processor and peripherals" and "KVM is to accelerate it if CPU has VT enabled", so I thought both QEMU and KVM are kernel modules.

Comment: Is it correct that libvirt is a server process, and VMM a client process? Is QEMU also a server to VMM?  What is the relation and difference between  QEMU and libvirt processes? Do all the four components communicate by  KVM <->QEMU <-> libvirt <-> VMM?

Comment: What’s the point in repeating [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/502750/what-is-the-relation-between-virtual-machine-manager-and-kvm-qemu/502752?noredirect=1#comment939521_502752) on different questions? This question has nothing to do with VMM and libvirt.

Comment: If you use KVM, you’ve got hardware acceleration (so with QEMU, `qemu-kvm` or the KVM “enable” option). I don’t know the equivalent in VirtualBox off-hand.

Comment: And yes, QEMU does *not* involve kernel modules itself.

Comment: @Tim that process should be called `libvirtd` and VMM is a client of it. libvirtd hide the complexity of different virtualization technology behind it, allow you to manage those containers or virtual machines by communicate with it(which is virsh or VMM does). But they're really not related to this question, since the question is about different virtual machine technology implementation. Not the management warper system.